# JsonException No _valueDeserializer on non entity field

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, fasterxml

This exception(No _valueDeserializer) happens from time to time (on random primitive fields) whenever i send a **JSON** object from front end to back end using **spring frame-work** and latest **Jackson**, **the weird thing is that this exception occurs only on non-relation fields (String,Long,etc).**

I've read [JsonException No _valueDeserializer assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972817/jsonexception-no-valuedeserializer-assigned) but i dont have an infinite recursion exception.

In the below code when I try to send **B** entity to be saved with a reference to **A** an exception will be thrown:
**JsonException No _valueDeserializer on B['a'] -> A['name']**

Example:

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "a" }, allowSetters = true)
    private List<B> b; 

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: it seems you need to use allowSetters when using @JsonIgnoreProperties