# Intermittent Jackson Model Mapper Reference Chain Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm encountering a weird issue with Jackson's model mapper when using the Spring Boot Framework. It seems that Jackson **sometimes** has issues mapping from the JSON payload to one of my DTOs. Strangely enough, this only happens if the endpoint having issues is NOT one of the first endpoints called when the server starts up. Here is the error:

```
2018-12-21 11:10:05.012 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(384) - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: No _valueDeserializer assigned
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@22361a02; line: 1, column: 208] (through reference chain: c.r.p.a.d.s.ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO["advisor"]->c.r.p.a.d.AdvisorDTO["lastModifiedBy"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No _valueDeserializer assigned
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@22361a02; line: 1, column: 208] (through reference chain: c.r.p.a.d.s.ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO["advisor"]->c.r.p.a.d.AdvisorDTO["lastModifiedBy"])
```

Below is the endpoint being called when this error happens. This error only happens if I call a few endpoints before the one below. If I call this endpoint first after the server starts up, it succeeds correctly.

```
/**
 * POST /subscriptions/subscribe -> Create account subscription.
 *
 * @param serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO the subscription information
 * @return the created subscription object
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/subscriptions/subscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<?> subscribe(@RequestBody ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO) {
    this.logger.error("Service Provider Subscription DTO:      " + ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO));
    try {
        SubscriptionDTO result = this.service.create(serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        this.logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorDTO("SUBSCRIPTION_CREATE_FAILED"));
}
```

If I change the controller to accept just a generic map, and then I use a org.modelmapper.ModelMapper to map it to the ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO, everything works fine, regardless of when I call the endpoint. Obviously, this is not the ideal solution however, since I lose all of the benefits of Spring Framework's RequestBody annotation.

```
/**
 * POST /subscriptions/subscribe -> Create account subscription.
 *
 * @param serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO the subscription information
 * @return the created subscription object
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/subscriptions/subscribe", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<?> subscribe(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO) {
    this.logger.error("Service Provider Subscription DTO:      " + ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO));
    try {
        ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO converted = this.modelMapper.map(serviceProviderSubscriptionDTO, ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO.class);
        SubscriptionDTO result = this.service.create(converted);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        this.logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorDTO("SUBSCRIPTION_CREATE_FAILED"));
}
```

Below are the DTOs for reference.

Service Provider Subscription DTO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO {
    /**
     * The payment source token.
     */
    protected String paymentSourceToken;
    /**
     * The Advisor reference.
     */
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("subscription")
    private AdvisorDTO advisor;

    public String getPaymentSourceToken() {
        return this.paymentSourceToken;
    }

    public void setPaymentSourceToken(String paymentSourceToken) {
        this.paymentSourceToken = paymentSourceToken;
    }

    public AdvisorDTO getAdvisor() {
        return this.advisor;
    }

    public void setAdvisor(AdvisorDTO advisor) {
        this.advisor = advisor;
    }
}
```

Subscription DTO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SubscriptionDTO {
    /**
     * Database identification number.
     */
    @Id
    protected Long id;
    /**
     * First and last name of the user who created the record in database.
     */
    protected String lastModifiedBy;
    /**
     * The Advisor reference.
     */
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "subscription", "lastModifiedBy" })
    private AdvisorDTO advisor;
    /**
     * The Service Provider Subscription.
     */
    private ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO serviceProviderSubscription;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return this.lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public AdvisorDTO getAdvisor() {
        return this.advisor;
    }

    public void setAdvisor(AdvisorDTO advisor) {
        this.advisor = advisor;
    }

    public ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO getServiceProviderSubscription() {
        return this.serviceProviderSubscription;
    }

    public void setServiceProviderSubscription(ServiceProviderSubscriptionDTO serviceProviderSubscription) {
        this.serviceProviderSubscription = serviceProviderSubscription;
    }
}
```

Advisor DTO

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AdvisorDTO {
    /**
     * Database identification number.
     */
    @Id
    protected Long id;
    /**
     * First and last name of the user who created the record in database.
     */
    protected String lastModifiedBy;
    /**
     * The subscription.
     */
    private SubscriptionDTO subscription;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return this.lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public SubscriptionDTO getSubscription() {
        return this.subscription;
    }

    public void setSubscription(SubscriptionDTO subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
    }
}
```

To me, this seems like some sort of model mapping cache issue, where other endpoints are caching some sort of instructions for the model mapper which are incompatible for this object. I don't know exactly what Jackson does with these payloads when they are read into the controllers, so I can only speculate. These errors are being thrown before any of my controller code runs.

Does anyone have any insight for me regarding what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Spring Boot: 1.5.3.RELEASE

Spring Core: 4.3.8.RELEASE

Jackson Core: 2.8.8

Java: 8

Comment: Is your issue by any chance related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972817/jsonexception-no-valuedeserializer-assigned)? It looks strikingly similar

Comment: It seems a bit similar, but I am already using the JsonIgnoreProperties annotation. Seems that the last person on that thread suggested what I'm doing. There must be a better solution than that.